# Obtain indices from .obj

Tags: opengl-es

I dont know opengl-es. but I must use features of .obj 3d model in my android app.
In .obj file, I can find Vertices, Texcoords and Normals. but there is no Indices and instead there are face elements.
Can anyone clearly explain me how to obtain indices from .obj file?

Comment: You need to read Wavefront object file specification

Comment: you mean this:
http://www.martinreddy.net/gfx/3d/OBJ.spec

Comment: Yes, something like that or even from wikipedia. Using that u l know how to get indices from faces, faces will be formed using indices only.

Comment: I just understood that "Each face can contain three or more elements.

f v1/vt1/vn1 v2/vt2/vn2 v3/vt3/vn3 .... "
but there is no method to obtain indices from face element..

Comment: I don't think u need a special method to get indices..!!!. Just split the string using delimiter and get the index value..!!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Possibly a little hard to write clearly because what OBJ considers a vertex is not what OpenGL considers a vertex. Let's find out...

An OBJ file establishes lists of obj-vertices (`v`), texture coordinates (`vt`), normals (`n`). You probably don't ever want to hand these to OpenGL (but skip to the end for the caveat). They're just a way for your loading code to establish the meaning of `v1`, `vt3`, etc.

The only place that openGL-vertices are specified is within the `f` statement. E.g. `v1/vt1/vn1` means "the OpenGL vertex with location, texture coordinate and normal as specified back in the list".

So a workable solution to loading is, in pseudocode:

- instantiate an empty hash map from `v/vt/vn` triples to opengl-vertex indices, an empty opengl-vertex list, and an empty list of indices for later supplication to `glDrawElements`;
- for each triple in the OBJ file:

  - look into the hash map to determine whether it is already in the opengl-vertex list and, if so, get the index and add it to your elements list;
  - if not then assign the next available index to the triple (so, this is just an incrementing number), put that into the hash map and the elements list, combine the triple and insert it into the opengl-vertex list.

You can try to do better than that by attempting to minimise the potential highly random access it implies to your opengl-vertex list at drawing time, but don't prematurely optimise.

---

Caveat:

If your GPU supports vertex texture fetch (i.e. texture sampling within the vertex shader) then you could just supply the triples directly to OpenGL, having accumulated the obj-vertices, etc, into texture maps, and do the indirect lookup in your vertex shader. With vertex texture fetch, textures really just become random access 2d arrays. However, many Android GPUs don't support vertex texture fetch (even if they support ES 3 which ostensibly makes it a requirement, as it allows an implementation to specify that it supports a maximum of zero samplers).